# DDD Domain vs Aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to wrap my head around DDD.

Say we have a **job board** website where `Organisations` can post jobs and an `Applicant` can apply.

Is my understanding correct that, there would be a `Recruitment` domain with:

- `JobPost` and `JobPostApplication` as aggregates
- `HiringOrganisation` and `Applicant` as entities of their respective aggregate

```
Recruitment
└── Model
    ├── Entities
    │   ├── Applicant
    │   └── HiringOrganisation
    │   └── Location
    ├── ValueObjects
    │   └── Salary
    │   └── EmploymentType
    ├── JobPost
    └── JobPostApplication
```

If so, how would:

- the `Applicant` relate to the `User` from the `Auth` domain
- the `HiringOrganisation` relate to the `Organisation` in the `Organisations` domain

Answer (score 2):

> how would
>   the Applicant relate to the User from the Auth domain
>   the HiringOrganisation relate to the Organisation in the Organisations domain

Typically: shared identifiers.  Some value (often an opaque token, like a UUID) is shared by both contexts, so that we can correlate messages that are talking about the "same" thing, in different spaces where the data evolves over time.